# Gnuplot: suppress warning

Tags: gnuplot

I have built a Gnuplot-Wrapper in C# that processes a lot of single plots at runtime. Each plot obtains its data from a data-file in ascii format representing a large matrix with floating point values. Very often the first line of a matrix contains only NaN-Values. That's why gnuplot is printing warnings to console like this:

`line 0: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values`

NaN-Values are ignored at plotting - this behaviour is appreciated because I'm plotting heatmaps with areas that do not hold values. That's why these warnings are not necessary in this case. They just slow down gnuplot.

Is there any way to turn off warnings like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no intrinsic way in gnuplot to suppress these warnings.

The only option I can think of is to redirect the stderr to /dev/null with something like `gnuplot yourfile.gp 2>/dev/null` or alternatively ignore them in your c# program.

Comment: Yeah. That would work. But I want to turn off warnings - not redirect or actively filter them